# Remove a key from a nested map in Java

Tags: java

I have a map object whose value is:

```
{Name={
    Id=9999, 
    status=OK, 
    Idn={
        source=TEST, 
        value=123, 
        TS=2018-11-14T18:10:33.998Z
    }
}}
```

I have to remove the value=123 part from it so that my final Map looks like:

```
{Name={
    Id=9999, 
    status=OK, 
    Idn={
        source=TEST, 
        TS=2018-11-14T18:10:33.998Z
    }
}}
```

the `.remove(key)` part would work on `"Name"` tag but I am unable to reach the nested `Name.Idn.value` and remove it.

Edited code:
My map is populated from `mongoTemplate.findOne()`

```
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> response    
Query query = new Query();
    Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("Name.Idn.value").is(123);
    query.addCriteria(criteria).fields().exclude("_id");
    response = mongoTemplate().findOne(query, Map.class, "dummy_col");
```

From response, while sending response back, the `Name.Idn.value` is to be removed.

Comment: Could you share an example Map (with Java code), it would help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess you have a `Map<String, Object> map` to be able to hold such different types as values, so you need to case first value as `Map<String, Map>` to be able to continue your path

```
((Map<String, Map<String, Object>>) map.get("Name")).get("idn").remove("source");
```

---

In fact yo have a `Map<String, Map<String, Object>> map`, so you know the first `get()` will return a `Map`, this is the second one that you need to cast

```
((Map<String, Object>) map.get("Name").get("idn")).remove("source");
```

Comment: @earl I've edit, you need to case the result from the second get, because of how is typed your Map

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have 3 levels of nested maps.

The value of `name` is a map, which has a key `Idn` with value that is also a map.

So, you would need a code that would look like this:

```
Map<String, Map<>> top = { ... };
Map<String, Map<>> name = top.get("Name");
Map<String, String> idn = name.get("Idn");

idn.remove("value");
```

You could also do it in one line like this:

```
Map <String, Map> top = { ... };

top.get("Name").get("Idn").remove("value");
```